# Spring @Autowired: how autowiring interface works

Tags: java, spring, interface, autowired

Please help me to understand how autowiring works with interfaces in Spring when implementation class extends another class. Since we can't create object for interface in Java, my understanding is Spring will inject instance of implementation class when using @Autowired annotation. In below case, why am I not able to call inherited method ( TestDAOImpl->save() ) when autowiring TestDAO inside TestServiceImpl?

```
Interface CommonDAO
{
    
    save();
}

Class CommonDAOImpl implements CommonDAO
{
    
    // define save();
}



Interface TestDAO

{
    
    User createUser ()
}

class TestDAOImpl extends CommonDaoImpl{
    
    //define createUser()
}


class TestServiceImpl implements TestService{
    
    @Autowired
    TestDAO testDao

    public User createUser(){
    //Able to call testDao.createUser();
    //Why I am not able to call call testDao.save()?
    //what is actually happening when autowiring interface? Spring not injecting instance for TestDAOImpl in this case?
    }

}
```

Comment: Your example does not work. You have a class trying to "implement" another class, and you have two unrelated interfaces. (The fact that a class implements interface `A` and `B` does not mean that if you declare its variable as `A` you see the `B` methods too.)

Comment: I think you have to `@Autowired` with `TestDAOImpl` class, not interface. And mapper-config.xml will search all DAOs and bind them with sql mapper xmls

Comment: Your class only knows about `TestDAO` it doesn't know about the `TestDAOImpl`. As `TestDAO` isn't a `CommonDAO` the `save` method isn't available, regardless of which implementation is being used.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Spring, but simply how interfaces work in Java. To do what you want, you either need to inject `CommonDAO`, or make sure that `TestDAO` extends  `CommonDAO`.

Answer (score 0):

You stated is the DAO layer two dimensions, but you only use one of them, and they don't have any correlation (inheritance, extension, internal calls) to ensure that you understand the interface between the scope and class inside the scope of the concept of later and try again, for example, you can make a subclass inherits CommonDAO inherit TestDAO at the same time, although this is not in line with the single responsibility princple, But in order for you to understand better, you can try